# Problem with Softmax decision boundary

Tags: neural-networks, linear-model, linear-algebra, softmax

While reading this paper: [sphere face](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08063.pdf) on page 2, it explains that original softmax boundary is given by: $$(W_1 −W_2)x+b_1 −b_2 = 0$$

While trying to obtain the boundary on a toy generated 2D dataset implementing own softmax regression, I have a matrix $W$ of size $(2,2)$ and a a vector $b$ of $(2,1)$ already trained, my $X$ is of shape $(100, 2)$.

I want to obtain my boundary vector but can't figure out how to calculate it by operations above because by subtracting column 1 and 2 of $W$ I get a vector of shape $(2,1)$ so the only way to multiply by $X$ is:
$$X\odot(W_1 - W_2)$$ 
Thus getting a vector of $(100,1)$ and that is not the boundary.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your $X$ contains all of your samples. One sample of yours, which is $x$, has dimension $(1,2)$, the one that the boundary equation uses. Secondly, you've trained your network and obtained $W_i$ and $b_i$, which completely defines your *boundary* equation. The $x$ in the equation is a general data vector $(x_1,x_2)$, not your data. After training your network, i.e obtaining your weights and biases, the boundary doesn't depend on your data anymore. You'll obtain something like $ax_1+bx_2+c=0$ after substituting $x=(x_1,x_2)$ to your equation.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I'd have to solve the equation for $x$ by subtracting the two columns of $W$ as coefficients and b as a constant?

Comment: When you do that, you'll have something like $ax_1+bx_2+c=0$, which is your boundary. This is the solution for $x$.